# C++ TlHelp32.h not working?

Tags: c++, header

I've included the TlHelp32.h header properly though I keep getting the message:

> "Error: identifier "CreateToolhelp32Snapshot" is undefined"

when attempting to use CreateToolhelp32Snapshot. When I used the "peek definition" feature in VS I found that there are errors within this header where in certain areas it says:

> "Error expected a ';'"

Any ideas how to fix this?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <TlHelp32.h> 
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Functions{

public:
    void playerHealthPrinter(){
        HANDLE hProcess;
        DWORD dwPID, dwProtection, dwCaveAddress;

        BOOL bPOn, bIOn, bProt;
        HANDLE hPID = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
```

Comment: Show some code, please.

Comment: You should include a [mcve] and the exact error. Keep in mind that this function is only available in Windows XP and later (per the docs), so you have to make sure it's enabled.

Comment: Added code. What's really weird is that I've copied and pasted a public headerfile and .cpp that also utilises this "CreateToolhelp32Snapshot" function yet there is no error with this public .cpp file? The header file i copied includes the TlHelp32.h though the .cpp does not, however when i add TlHelp32.h to the .cpp the "CreateToolhelp32Snapshot" instantly causes an error.

Comment: Hmmm, when i compile the public code i used, it throws over a 100 syntax errors in the TlHelp32.h though when i peek definition there are no errors in that file. Is VS broken? EDIT: I opened the TlHelp32.h on its own and there are errors everywhere.

Answer (score 21):

Never include Win32 headers *before* `<windows.h>`. The following should work, instead:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h> // <-- include *after* windows.h
```

If it still doesn't work then please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including the relevant headers and version of VS.

Comment: Thank you, sir, it worked! Do you know why we need to include Windows.h before we include Win32?

Comment: @KulaGGin `tlHelp32.h` depends on macros set up (indirectly) by `windows.h` for example `#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)`. There is in fact this comment at the very top of `tlHelp32.h`: "*NOTE: windows.h/winbase.h must be #included first*". The same applies to (most) other Win32 headers.